# How to make a strategy enter in the middle of current bar?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script

I tried a very simple strategy as below,

```
VB_signal = (close - open) > high[1] - low[1]

strategy.entry("VB_buy", strategy.long, when = VB_signal)
strategy.close("VB_buy", when = barstate.isnew)
```

when **current price goes over open price + previous bar's range** (high - low), **immediately enters in the middle of current bar.**

But when I backtested this strategy, **the strategy always entered after current bar close** (beggining of next bar) **How can I make this strategy enter in the middle of current bar?**

In the image below,

[Wanted to enter in the middle of second bar, but it enters on 3rd bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7znJv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Both during historical and real-time calculation, code is calculated on bar **closes** by default.

Source: [Backtesting and Forwardtesting](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Strategies#Backtesting_and_forwardtesting)

Comment: I see, so there is no way I can make it "enter" in the middle of current bar??

Comment: For strategies, no. You can try to do that with an indicator and set an alert for that condition but then you will have a lot of repainting issues.